# Why do we even talk about $\mathbf{R}^2$ when describing complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

**Background.** Just started learning Complex Analysis, absolute beginner.

$\def\C{\mathbf{C}}$
$\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$
Let $A\subseteq\C$ and let $f:A\to\C$ be a complex valued function.
With $x,y\in\R$, we can say $x+iy:=z\in\C$. For a given $z\in\C$, we can say $f(z) = w$ for some $w\in\C$. In particular, there are two real numbers $u,v\in\R$ such that $f(z)=u+iv$.

To this point, in every textbook or notes I've come across, the author always writes the following:

Let $u,v:\R^2\to\R$ be functions such that for two real $x,y\in\R$ and $x+iy\in A$, we have $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+i\cdot v(x,y)$.

And continue using this terminology throughout their texts.

Why is $\R^2$ used here? Wouldn't it be equivalent (and less cumbersome) to just say that $u,v:\C\to\R$ and call it done?
Is there any benefit of thinking of $u,v$ with domain $\R^2$ rather than domain $\C$, or is it purely convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to do what you suggest, but the reason that $u$ and $v$ are taken to be functions of two arguments is that usually, the very next thing that is written down is the Cauchy-Riemann conditions
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},
$$
which are very easy to notate for functions of two arguments, but much more awkward if the domain of $u$ and $v$ was $\mathbf{C}$, where we would have to write something like
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \Re(z)} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial \Im(z)}, \quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \Im(z)} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial \Re(z)},
$$
for which you'd have to explain carefully what you even mean by these partial derivatives, as it's not a standard use of partial derivative notation.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty interesting question. In short, there is a benefit to thinking of $u,v$ with domain $R^2$ rather than domain $C$ as in the definition you provided. Because it not a matter of thinking they have domain $R^2$. It would actually be mathematically incorrect to say $u,v$ as functions have domain $C$. So yes there is a difference and it is not a convention.

This is an understandable mistake to make so let's do some clarifications and I'm sure it will make more sense then.

So let us break it down.

Consider the first definition you provided:

Let ⊆ and let :→ be a complex valued function. With ,∈, we can say +:=∈. For a given ∈, we can say ()= for some ∈. In particular, there are two real numbers ,∈ such that ()=+.

This definition tends to not take the stance of perceiving $u,v$ as functions.

Now the second definition you provided is a more "explicit" definition in the sense it states essentially an implied point that $u,v$ depend on $x,y$ when $z$ is expressed in cartesian form $x+iy$.

Let ,:2→ be functions such that for two real ,∈ and +∈, we have (+)=(,)+⋅(,).

Now I'm sure $f(x+iy) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ makes sense.

Now we know $u,v\in R$ so the codomain is $R$ and both $u,v$ take inputs $x,y \in R$. So both $u$ and $v$ take two real inputs hence the domain of both $u$ and $v$ is $R^2$.

Thus $u,v:R^2\rightarrow R$

Using $C$ as the domain in this context does make much sense. I can clarify further if there is still any confusion.

Hope this Helps :)